# Filter data coming from API with Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Im using slick slider in Nuxt im getting the images from an API with Axios

The API look like this :

```js
"images_selection": [
  {
    title: 'Global Landing',
    slug: 'global-landing-1',
    id: 113,
    images: [
      {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        file_extension: 'jpeg',
        position: 0,
        url: 'https://####images',
        type: 0,
        link: '',
        id: 3603,
        video_link: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Home Slider 1',
    slug: 'home-slider-1',
    id: 331,
    images: [
      {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        file_extension: 'jpeg',
        position: 0,
        url: 'https://###images',
        type: 0,
        link: '',
        id: 5773,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

My Axios :

```js
async mounted() {
  const response = await axios.get('/api/')
  this.resultsimages = response.data.images_selection.filter(r => r.slug = home-slider-1)
},
```

Im trying to get the image only in "Home Slider 1" with a filter `.filter(r => r.slug = home-slider-1);`

But im doing something wrong what will be the best way to target only the home slider 1 ?

---

EDIT: here is my page where I am not able to loop on the fetched images.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="home-slider">
      <VueSlickCarousel
        :arrows="false"
        :dots="true"
        :slidesToShow="3"
        :rows="1"
        :slidesPerRow="3"
        :autoplay="true"
        :fade="true"
      >
        <div class="slide1">
          <div v-for="result in resultsimages" :key="result.id">
            <div class="img1">
              <img
                v-for="images in result.images"
                :key="images.id"
                :src="images.url"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </VueSlickCarousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      resultsimages: [],
      data: [],
    }; 
  async mounted() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/", {
      headers: {
        "X-AUTH-TOKEN": "####",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    this.resultsimages = data.images_selection.filter((image) => (image) =>
      image.slug === "home-slider-1"
    );
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I heavily formatted your question, especially for the axios part by using only `async/await` and not a mix of both `async/await` + `.then`.

This is how the block should look like

```js
async mounted() {
  const { data } = await axios.get('/api/')
  this.resultsimages = data.images_selection.filter((image) => (image) => image.slug === 'home-slider-1')
},
```

Please format your code with more effort next time.

Comment: Thank you Kissu i will be more careful about my format

Comment: No issues my friend. Is my answer working ?

Comment: Im trying your answer Kissu but axios dont get images now im trying to see {{resultsimages}} for see wich data is retrieve

Comment: Filter give you the matched object, hence the one with `title, slug, id, images etc...`, if you need only the images, go one step deeper by calling `.images` on the filtered object when you pass it to your template.

Comment: Ok Kissu i will try that thank you. :). coz  now it looks like the filter dont apply on "images_selection"  coz in {{resultsimages}} i still have the  slug: 'global-landing-1',

Comment: At this point, we will heavily need the remaining code to help you because I don't know what is your template looking like.